# Download not working using filetransfer plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I used IonicNative plugin for downloading pdf files.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/

I can see download complete using alert,but cannot see any download happening.

```
private filetransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create(); 
  const url = 'https://www.example.com/example%20test.pdf'; 
  this.filetransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'example%20test.pdf').then((entry) =>
          {
                  alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
          },
 (error) => {
                  alert(error);
});
```

Is this the correct way to do or am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the correct way to do it.

I'm not quit sure what you mean with "you cannot see any download happening", but I'm assuming you can't find the file in the file system (otherwise just let me know).

In this case your saving the file in a private data storage, specified by:

```
this.file.dataDirectory
```

If you replace this.file.dataDirectory with this.file.externalDataDirectory, you will find the document in your file system (something like: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.project.name).

The ionic native documentation is not that good in this case, see the cordova file plugin documentation instead, where the different possibilitiers are listed:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files.

Comment: Hi @JudgeFudge I have a similar problem with Cordova filetransfer. The download on success function is called right away (without invoking in progress!) and when I browse for the file it is there but empty ( 0 bytes). The server I am downloading from is a bit slow (I tried from the browser, it took longer than usual to download). I am not sure what to do!