# ionic 3 - file download with FileTransfer not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In an angular/ionic app, I have the following code to download a pdf from the internet.

```
public pdfDownload(){
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        const mime = 'application/pdf';
        const pdfFile = 'http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf';
        // alert(this.file.dataDirectory);
        fileTransfer.download(pdfFile, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf', true)
            .then((entry) => {
                alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
            }, (error) => {
                // handle error
            });
    }
```

But now Im looking for this file in my android phone but I cant find it. The path in my phone is [image]
There are no files. Where did I download it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic file download not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585458/ionic-file-download-not-working)

Comment: did you found any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use **this.file.externalDataDirectory+'file.pdf'** instead of ***this.file.dataDirectory+'file.pdf'*** in second parameter of function  fileTransfer.download(1 parameter,2 parameter,3 parameter);

e.g.

**fileTransfer.download(pdfFile, this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'file.pdf', true)**

Comment: same.. for me, it doesn't do anything. As if promise never returns. Not even an error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. File saver download method

```
    async downloadFile() {
          await this.fileTransfer.download("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/23/21/soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg", this.file.externalRootDirectory + 
          '/Download/' + "soap-bubble-1959327_960_720.jpg");
        }
```

2. Get permission method for save file in user Android devices

```
       getPermission() {
              this.androidPermissions.hasPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .then(status => {
                  if (status.hasPermission) {
                    this.downloadFile(); // your file transfer method 
                  } 
                  else {
                    this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                      .then(status => {
                        if(status.hasPermission) {
                          this.downloadFile(); // your file transfer method
                        }
                      });
                  }
                });
            }
```

3. Important note:

   Many of them use `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, that's why it will not store your file. You should  try `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in permissions.

100% it will work on ionic 4^.